# How can I display image and play audio from a URL given in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

link to JSON data -> http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio
On executing the program in browser it displays URL and not the image or audio like this ->

http://hck.re/3Cm0IX

http://hck.re/5dh4D5

http://hck.re/U1bRnt

http://hck.re/eLtjUb

My code:

```
<body>

<div id="cover_img" width="150px" height="150px">  </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function(){
        var myjsondata = request.response; //request.response contains all our JSON data
        showdata(myjsondata);


    } 

    function showdata(data){

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            document.write(data[i].cover_image +"<br>");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is `show_cover_images`? I don't see that in the code you shared.
 Also, in `showdata` itself you are showing `cover_image`. So where is the problem?

Comment: You can run the code it displays URL and not image how can I display image in browser.@PankajShukla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `<IMG>` tags and populate their `src` property like below:

```
function showdata(data){

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write(data[i].cover_image +"<br>");
        var str = "<IMG src='"+data[i].cover_image+"'/>";
        document.write(str);
        document.write("<br/>");
        str = "<a href='"+data[i].url+"'>"+data[i].song+"</a>";
        document.write(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: so basically you created an img tag so now if I want to play song from URL then should I make a button and then onclick it should start playing audio can I follow same procedure for audio also

Comment: How can I change the width and height of image can I do like this:                 var str = "<img id='myimg' src='"+data[0].cover_image+"'/>";
document.getElementById("myimg").width = "250px";
document.getElementById("myimg").height = "250px";

Comment: See my edit to create hyperlinks for the song. When you click on the link song plays.

Comment: You cannot have same id for many elements. So create img elements with different ids.

Comment: So can I do like this I want to print single cover_image of required width and height but here in my code it doesn't work.                              `function showdata(data){ var x = document.createElement("IMG"); x.setAttribute("src", "data[0].cover_image"); x.setAttribute("width", "250"); x.setAttribute("height", "350");  document.body.appendChild(x); }`

Comment: @rockstone You need to remove `"` from `"data[0].cover_image"` and change it to `data[0].cover_image`. Also, you need to put for loop if you want to show all images.